# Using the do-while loop that will terminate after 3 attempts

Tags: java

An exercise that I am stuck on is one using the do-while loop.  I am supposed to prompt the user to enter the password, then re-enter the password again.  If these passwords match then they will gain access.  If the two passwords do not match then I am supposed to prompt the user to enter the password again 3 more times.  After the third time it will tell them access is denied.  I am having difficulty distinguishing what goes where in the do-while loop.

This is what I have (updated)...still confused as to why it is not terminating:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

    String password1;    
    String password2;    

    int i = 1;

    do {

      System.out.println("Please enter your password");
      password1 = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Please re-enter your password");
      password2 = sc.nextLine();

    } while(!password1.equals(password2) && i<=3);

    i++;

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: `while(i <= 3 && !password1.equals(password2));`

Comment: `i` is been incremented outside of the `do-while` loop, so it will never be incremented while your checking the password.  You also never give the user an opportunity to re-enter the password within the `do-while` loop.  Start by getting it work once (without the loop) and the wrap the loop around that, been sure to include the required exit logic for the loop

Comment: what would the correct exit logic be? I have been using if(i>3) then access is denied under the while portion.  That hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your = comparison is wrong.  If you want to make sure two strings have the same value, you need to use the String equals method.  '=' is an assignment operator `if (a=b) {}` doesn't compile, and '==' checks if two variables are pointing to the same thing.  `if (a==b) {}` won't always succeed (see example below).  The String equals method always looks at the actual value represented by a String.

```
String a = "1";
String b = "12".substring(0,1);
a == b // false
a.equals(b) // true
```

Now with that out of the way - there are lots of ways you can get the exit condition.  If you want to do it all in one statement, you can change `i<=3` in your while condition `i++ <= 3`.  My preference is to separate the two conditions like this

```
do {
    ...
    if (password.equals(password2)) {
        break;
    }
} while (i++ <= 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

it never ends because you never increment the  `i` counter, the `i++;` should be inside the do while statement. Try initializing `i = 0` , and increment it at the begining of each operation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

      String password1;    
      String password2;    

      int i = 0;

      do {
       i++;

       System.out.println("Please enter your password");
       password1 = sc.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Please re-enter your password");
       password2 = sc.nextLine();

     } while(!password1.equals(password2) && i<=3);
    }
}
```